# ASP.NET VB DataTable Option Strict on prohibits operands of type Object '>'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET VB. I am tring to make sure one date is greater than the other.

I have the following:

```
    For Each row1 In dtDataTable2.Rows

      If (row1("ActualDate") > row1("DueDate")) Then

      End If
    Next
```

Both ActualDate and DueDate are dates.
I get the following:

Option Strict on prohibits operands of type Object '>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your code to something like:

```
If (CDate(row1("ActualDate")) > CDate(row1("DueDate"))) Then
```

it will work.

The value type returned by the default property on a DataRow (which is the Item property) is an object, so you need to convert the object to the type of data you need.